# header location error redirecting

Tags: php, header, location

Hello I am trying to read a file which contain a url where I want to redirect I am using this

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$link = fread($myfile,filesize($link));
fclose($myfile);
header("Location: $link");
```

The browser show me an error "The Page isn´t redirect correctly"

The file test.txt contains

```
http://www.google.es
```

Comment: stupid but necessary question. Have you tried to do an echo $link and check if there isn't hidden chars?

Comment: Why don't you just call `file_get_contents()` if you want to read the whole file at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this statement here,

```
$link = fread($myfile,filesize($link));
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function expects the file path as it's argument, but you're passing an *undefined variable* `$link`.

So the above statement should be like this:

```
$link = fread($myfile,filesize($file));
```

Also, use `exit();` after `header(...);` because `header(...);` itself is not sufficient to redirect the user to a different page.

```
header("Location: $link"); 
exit();
```

Comment: yours is the better (explained) answer. I was writing up mine as I saw the yellow box on top stating an answer was given lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, sometimes it happens to me also. ;-)

Comment: and indeed to add the `exit;` after header. I was going to also suggest it (TBH).

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong variable for

```
filesize($link)
```

which should be `$file`

```
filesize($file)
```

---

(Edit):

**Debugging procedure** (and with [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set to catch and display).

Having commented out the header and echoing the `$link` variable

```
$file = "test.txt";
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo $link = fread($myfile,filesize($link));
fclose($myfile);
// header("Location: $link");
```

...you would have been presented with the following notice/warning:

> Notice: Undefined variable: link in /path/to/file.php on line x
>   Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /path/to/file.php on line x

Since `fread()` couldn't figure out the `filesize`, it failed to to "read" it.

And of course as Rajdeep stated in his (much better) answer, to add `exit;` after header. Yours would have (most likely) worked, but it is indeed better practice.